# boost::filesystem relative path and current directory?

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

How can I use `boost::filesystem::path` to specify a relative path on Windows? This attempt fails:

```
boost:filesystem::path full_path("../asset/toolbox"); // invalid path or directory.
```

Maybe to help me debug, how to get the current working directory with boost::filesystem?

Comment: Just to clarify, I solved my problem. The above method is correct for relative path access. However, in MSVS the current working directory was not what I had expected. hmuelner's currentpath() helped.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
getcwd = boost::filesystem::path full_path(boost::filesystem::current_path());
```

Example:

```
boost::filesystem::path full_path(boost::filesystem::current_path());
std::cout << "Current path is : " << full_path << std::endl;
```

To access `current_path` one needs to add `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`.

Comment: there seems to be a flaw here, this is not a valid C++ expression, is there missing something in between boost::filesystem::path and full_path?

Comment: This is not a valid C++ expression, but a short-cut notation for the answer. In modern C++ you could write: auto cwd = boost::filesystem::current_path();

Answer (score 20):

Try the [`system_complete`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#system_complete) function.

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

fs::path full_path = fs::system_complete("../asset/toolbox");
```

This mimics exactly how the OS itself would resolve relative paths.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change to previous directory then try something like this:

```
boost::filesystem::path full_path( boost::filesystem::current_path() );
std::cout << "Current path is : " << full_path << std::endl;

//system("cd ../"); // change to previous dir -- this is NOT working
chdir("../"); // change to previous dir -- this IS working

boost::filesystem::path new_full_path( boost::filesystem::current_path() );
std::cout << "Current path is : " << new_full_path << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type "../your/path" aren't you specifying a unix-like path? I think what you should do to get system specific paths is:

```
boost:filesystem::path full_path(".." / "asset" / "toolbox");
```

In this case the '/' is an operator concatenating paths in a system specific way and is not part of the path that you specify.

Comment: Not really...  You're specifying a path in the internal boost::filesystem format, which is somewhat unix-like.  I also like the operator notation better though.  You'd have to do something like path full_path = path("..") / "asset" / "toolbox";

Comment: And in windows you can use `/` as directory delimiter as well.

Comment: must be `boost:filesystem::path full_path(boost:filesystem::path(".." )/ "asset" / "toolbox");`